# Количество аргументов функции

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Недавно был [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759109/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-n-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) о том, как объявить функцию с n аргументами заданного типа. У меня возник противоположный вопрос. Как узнать количество аргументов функции?

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(float, int){

}

int main(){
    std::cout << doTemplateMagic(foo); //2
}
```

Comment: А что выводить для `printf`, например? :)

Comment: @Harry, ошибка компиляции будет в самый раз

Comment: @Harry, хотя, думаю, там можно будет что-нибудь специфицировать или перегрузить для функций, у которых в конце элипсисис идет, и выдавать -1. Но для простоты можно не думать об этом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost.TypeTraits, например

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

void f(int, char) {}

int n = boost::function_traits<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(&f)>>::arity;
```

Answer (score 7):

Можно использовать темплейт с переменным числом параметров:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename R, typename ... Types> constexpr size_t getArgumentCount( R(*f)(Types ...))
{
   return sizeof...(Types);
}

//----------------------------------    
// Test it out with a few functions.
//----------------------------------    

void foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
}

int bar()
{
   return 0;
}

int baz(double)
{
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << getArgumentCount(foo) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getArgumentCount(bar) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getArgumentCount(baz) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
3
0
1
```

Или использовать этот метод:

```
template <typename R, typename ... Types> 
constexpr std::integral_constant<unsigned, sizeof ...(Types)> getArgumentCount( R(*f)(Types ...))
{
   return std::integral_constant<unsigned, sizeof ...(Types)>{};
}

// Guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time
size_t count = decltype(getArgumentCount(foo))::value;
```

или

```
// Most likely evaluated at compile time
size_t count = getArgumentCount(foo).value;
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797770/get-function-parameters-count

Answer (score 2):

Немного покритикую остальные ответы, приводя цитату:

> “Don't try to write helper code to detect PMFs/PMDs and dispatch on them -- it is an absolute nightmare. PMF types are the worst types by far in the core language.”

Используйте [Boost.CallableTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/callable_traits/doc/html/index.html)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/callable_traits.hpp>

namespace ct = boost::callable_traits;

int main() {
    auto lamda = [](int, float&, const char*){};
    using lam = decltype(lamda);
    static_assert(std::tuple_size_v<ct::args_t<lam>> == 3);
}
```